# How to handle XMLHttpRequest POST request with Indy?

Tags: delphi, xmlhttprequest, indy

I have troubles sending an `XMLHttpRequest` request with `TIdHTTP`. Here is my header:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cache-control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Faces-Request:partial/ajax
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language:de-DE
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Content-Length:517
```

Here is the response header:

```
(Status-Line):HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:Mon, 21 Jun 2021 01:02:28 GMT
Server:Apache
X-ISPI-PERF:[Apache D=28068us b=0%]
X-ISPI-REQ-ID:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge
Pragma:no-cache
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=xxxx; Path=/air; Secure
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Content-Type-Options:no-sniff
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=[; includeSubDomains]
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=98
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:9642
```

How can I handle the response to get the full Content every time? The problem is that sometimes I get only 2000 bytes instead of 9600. There is no difference if I use a `TMemoryStream` or a `String` to get the response.

Here is my code:

```pascal
idHttpA := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
idHttpA.HTTPOptions := [hoTreat302Like303];
lIOHandlerA := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
lIOHandlerA.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
lIOHandlerA.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
//lIOHandlerA.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2; *must be deleted because of SSLVersions 
idHttpA.IOHandler := lIOHandlerA;  
....
try
  res := idHttpA.Post('https://server/Start.xhtml', List);
except
  on e:EIdSocketError do
    ShowMessage('EIdSocketError: ' + e.Message);
  on e:EIdReadTimeout do
    ShowMessage('EIdReadTimeout: ' + e.Message);
  on e:EIDHttpProtocolException do
    ShowMessage('EIDHttpProtocolException: ' + IntToStr(e.ErrorCode));
  on e:Exception do
    ShowMessage('Exception: ' + e.Message);
end;
```

Following is the response headers I get via `TIdHTTP.Response.RawHeaders`:

```
Date: Mon, 21 Jun 2021 18:30:22 GMT
Server: Apache
X-ISPI-PERF: [Apache D=45046us b=2%]
X-ISPI-REQ-ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxx.3; Path=/air; Secure
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: no-sniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=[; includeSubDomains]
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Connection: close
```

Comment: If the response claims `Content-Length:9642`, then `TIdHTTP` will read exactly 9642 bytes, no more, no less.  So if you are only getting 2000 bytes, something else is going on. Either the `Content-Length` is wrong, or something in between you and the server is interfering. Also, on a side side, you should get rid of the assignment of `lIOHandlerA.SSLOptions.Method`, it doesn't belong and will override your assignment of `lIOHandlerA.SSLOptions.SSLVersions`

Comment: Remy Lebeau, this is response header is from HTTPAnalyzer. from idHttpA.Response.ContentLength i got everytime -1;

Comment: The `TIdHTTP.Response.ContentLength` property will be `-1` only if there is no `Content-Length` header present at all, or if its value can't be parsed as an `Int64`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/pnRvjzJ here both headers from Analyzer, i have read that if it dynamic response, it will be returned -1

Comment: What does "dynamic response" mean?  What does the content of  `TIdHTTP.Response.RawHeaders` look like when things aren't working the way you expect? Please [edit] your question to show that.

Comment: i post now Response.RawHeaders, also i deleted lIOHandlerA.SSLOptions.Method.

Comment: You can clearly see that what HTTPAnalyzer is receiving is not what `TIdHTTP` is receiving. There is no `Content-Length` present in the response headers that `TIdHTTP` is receiving, and there is no `Transfer-Encoding`, but there is `Connection: close`, which means `TIdHTTP` will read until the connection is closed. There is also a `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header, which means the content has been compressed, which is due to your `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate` request header. Unless you are prepared to decompress the content, you should not be asking for compression to begin with

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank You very much! i add Compressor `idHttpA.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(idHttpA)` and now its work fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that **HTTPAnalyzer** show different response header to **TIdHTTP**,
after i check ResponseHeaders with `TIdHTTP.Response.RawHeaders`, i got response `Content-Encoding: gzip`, that didn't show **HTTPAnalyzer**, than i add Compressor
`idHttpA.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(idHttpA)` and the code working fine.

Thank you @RemyLebeau.